# know if current() is a element or an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Working on an XSLT sheet, I end up in a template with some `current()` xpath. I would like to know if it refers to an attribute or to an element.

Actually, I do not manage to do what I want using the template filters `select="./@*"`or `select="./*"`, because I want to get all the elements or attributes in one shot, and apply a different treatment depending on the type, in the same template.

Comment: Can you provide input XML and desired Output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds rather as if you want to set up different templates for the different nodes with e.g. `match="*` and `match="@*"`.

If you really want to check inside a template then you can use `<xsl:if test="self::*">` to test whether it is an element node and in XSLT 2 and later also with `<xsl:if test="self::attribute()">` whether it is an attribute. In XSLT/XPath 2 and later there is also the `. instance of element()` respectively `. instance of attribute()` test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with `<xsl:if test="self::*">` I could achieve to do what I wanted.